# How to set autolayout constraint for UITextView

Tags: ios, uiview, ios7, uitextview, nslayoutconstraint

I have tried a lot to set auotolayout constraint for UITextView. But when i run , i get blank screen . I tried the same way in UIButton , that worked !!!!!

Is there any property to be set to assign constraint for UITextView ????

```
UITextView *text1;
text1=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 100, 30)];
[text1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
set.text1=@"asjdgajsdbasbfbsdfbsdbfbsd";

[text1 sizeToFit];
set.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
[self.view addSubview:text1];   


NSLayoutConstraint *constraint;    
constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:text1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:1.f];

[self.view addConstraint:constraint];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes like say @P.Sami you need more constraints, because line 

`set.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;`

disable autoresizeMask it mean your frame not working more. And all frames colculated by constraints.
in your event only one constraint describe this: `constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:text1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:1.f];`
This constraint told: "text1.bottom like self.view.bottom * 1 + 1" First it's not equal bottom edge text1 and superview but offset on 1 point down. Second we don't know what about with heights, wight, x, y? 
For simple example just add addition constrints:

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[text]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{text1}]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[text]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{text1}]];
```

it's told to text1 be like self.view frame by Verticale and Horizontale